# Codeigniter search a column with text value using or_like

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am attempting to search on a `mysql` database using a codeigniter and using the active record `or_like` so my database looks like this.

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |    search_column    |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | dog,cat,mouse,horse |
|  2 | pig,lion,tiger      |
|  3 | eagle               |
+----+---------------------+
```

So my first approach was using the `where_in` cause my input came from a checkbox group and returns an array values and i store it into a variable `$term = array('cat','dog','lion')`

`$this->db->where_in('search_column', $term);`

But above method did not work so i tried below method.

```
foreach($term as $row){
  $this->db->or_like('search_column', $row);
}
```

And no luck either so the target output must show the result based on a array of string. any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the values from a given set you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
foreach($term as $row){
    $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET(".$row.",search_column) >", 0);
}
```

Note: This type of design is considered as a bad design and you should normalize your structure, I suggest you to have a look at [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Improvements

Create a table for animals and a junction table to relate your main table and animals

animals

```
id  name
1   cat
2   dog
3   lion
```

junction table

```
tid(main table pk) animal_id (animal table pk)
1                  1
1                  2
1                  3
```

Remove `search_column` from main table, this way you don't have any redundant data, searching and optimization would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If haven't another query condition, you can try a inequal condition first.

```
$this->db->where('0=1');
foreach($term as $row){
  $this->db->or_like('search_column', $row);
}
```